# MATLAB .fig file altering scatter point color

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, figure, scatter

I have 3 separate .fig files, formed from plot() function calls, which plot 8 different points on an xy scale.

The 8 points are the same 8 across the 3 figures, but due to the automatic colouring order of the plot() function, are different colours on the 3 figures. I want to post-process the 3 .fig files to have each of the 8 points be the same colour in the three plots.

[image: These are the three plots]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces your issue. This should not be a problem unless you're doing something to the `ColorOrder` of your plots. Each axes uses the same order and starting point by default.

Comment: Hi Excaza thanks for your reply. I run a code which has generated 3 separate plots. It calculates the mean of a series of calculations and plots them on an xy. Currently the 3 .fig files I have give 'red' to the point with the highest mean, then 'orange' etc. The 3 different figures I have currently have a different order of max-->min means, and as such 'point A' is red on one plot, and lime green on the other. I want every 'point' to be the same color regardless of their downward cascading mean value on each plot

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @excaza I have uploaded a photo to the question description illustrating the 3 plots

Comment: What is unclear about my request?

Comment: @excaza I do not understand what you mean by a 'minimal example'. I am not sure even where to begin with altering the colour of the markers on the plots I have attached on the original question

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody is going to be able to help you without being able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @excaza I'm sorry mate this is my first time on Stackoverflow (as you probably could tell posting your .gif on your chatroom :)). I can post the .fig files I have if that helps? I don't know where to begin with the code to alter the colors of these markers on the plots I already have, and that's what I want help with

Comment: I don't want code to alter the markers of the plots you already have. I want a minimal set of code that *generates* the plots you already have.

Comment: You're not able to  help me without this? These .fig files were created by someone else and do not have easy access to the code.

Comment: Are you sure you're giving your input variables to `plot` *in the same order** for each `plot` call? The `legend` order typically reflects the order of variables in a plot. You can also see that the color order is the same in each figure, since the colors *in the `legend`* are the same. Just the labels are mixed up, probably because you're calling `plot` with a mixed-up order of your variables.